# How to create VBSCRIPT(.vbs) file using Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition?

Tags: visual-studio, vbscript

Could some one explain me on how to create VBSCRIPT(.vbs) file using Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition?

I want to practice VBSCRIPT programs by using Visual Studio 2010 Express edition.

Please assist on how to get started?

Regards,Srihari

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2017 debugging vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44226237/visual-studio-2017-debugging-vbscript). This is about VS2017, but the same applies to VS2010 as well.

Comment: Hi as of now I want to understand on how to create Visual Basic Script in Visual Studio 2010 Express edition, debugging I will do it once script is in place.

Comment: Create any other type of plain text file (for example .cs or *.cpp), then rename to .vbs.

Comment: Or create a local text file, rename it to "someName.vbs" and then open it with VS, but what's the benefit that you'd get from that? It'd be simply an editor like any other editor until you want to debug (which is the part that's explained in the linked question). So, unless you want to _debug_, you can use any editor you want (including VS2010 IDE). Visual Studio doesn't have a VBScript project template if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Ahmed, thanks for inputs just like (.vb) script cant i create (.vbs) script in visual studio 2010 express edition? I want to basically write a (.vbs) program in visual studio IDE what is the step by step procedure for it? Kindly assist

Comment: Like I said, there's no such thing is VBScript project in VS, so it's not exactly the same as dealing with .vb files in a project (of any type). There are two things here. 1) Writing the script --> you can do that in an external editor or create the file and open it with VS and start writing the script. 2) Debugging the script --> As mentioned above, refer to the linked question for how to do that using VS.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Any other editors can't do this: http://const.me/tmp/vs2017-vbs-edit.png

Comment: The same applies to VS2010! It can't do that too, that's what I'm trying to tell you. You can still use VS though as I explained above. If you're interested, there are, however, editors that [do that and allows you to debug as well](https://www.vbsedit.com/).