# How to debug vbscript with Visual Studio Community (2019)

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, vbscript

I'd like to find a free solution to debug vbscripts, and I tried Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition. I did the very basic installation with only one additional component, the Just-In-Time debugger. I ran all the following steps as administrator.

I have created the file `Script2.vbs` with this very simple script:

```
a=1
b=1/0
c=1
```

I started the command line (cmd.exe) and entered `cscript.exe /x "C:\...\Script2.vbs` 
[image: cscript debug vbs]

The script is executed and fails as expected at line 2 but

> the problem is that the Just-In-Time debugger doesn't start.

(I expect the popup which is below "The Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger window appears" in this [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/just-in-time-debugging-in-visual-studio))

I have found in [this question about the previous version of the Community Edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44226237/visual-studio-2017-debugging-vbscript) that there should be the option "Script", but I don't have it:

[image: visual studio community options debugger jit script]

Note also that if I try to start the script from Visual Studio Community, the menu Debug > Start debugging is grayed out:

[image: visual studio community start debugging grayed out]

My main question is:

> Is the feature of debugging scripts turned off with Visual Studio **Community Edition**?

(which leads to the second question: is there a solution to debug VBS scripts for free?)

Comment: with my copy of VS 2019 Community this works as described - a new instance of VS 2019 is opened and i am able to step through the code, having run cscript /x somescript.vbs in CMD as Administrator

Comment: @hello_earth I guess that it works because `scd10en.exe` exists in your system, as Mark explained, the issue is that it's no more provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are still interested, there is a way to fix Visual Studio Community. It's likely some missing pre-requisites. Therefore you need to "Modify" the installed options and find "Script" debugging options in the Individual Components setup.

For example this is my minimum set of components.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I just checked now, "Just-In-Time debugger" was not selected and after I added it, this works and I will post a separated answer to detail all the steps.

Comment: TGFSO - Thank God For Stack Overflow!  Trying to debug a little vintage VBS script from back in 2009 on an older Server 2012 OS and your debug option become a bit limited.  Classic scd10en.exe from 1997 still works, but it's a bit cumbersome.  Visual Studio Community 2022 doesn't install properly on Server 2012 and will not work trying to attach Just-In-Time debugger.  Visual Studio Community 2019 works perfectly when following the procedure described by peregrinus and @Sandra-Rossi Thanks for documenting this and saving the day!

Answer (score 3):

You can download the VBS debugger from my OneDrive https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvqkaKIXzvDieQeOGgxLJICZ-uY?e=3r5B91

It is called `scd10en.exe`.

It has disappeared from MS's web site.

Comment: Thank you. I'm sure `scd10en.exe` works because I had used it some time ago, but do you know a more official free solution?

Comment: That's the only one I know off.

Comment: FWIW, the official download is archived in the wayback machine of the internet archive here: https://web.archive.org/web/20150302031023/http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22185&6B49FDFB-8E5B-4B07-BC31-15695C5A2143=1

Direct link to the DL: https://web.archive.org/web/20140127135015/http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/7/d/77d8df05-6fbc-4718-a319-be14317a6811/scd10en.exe

Answer (score 0):

peregrinus gave the right answer so I Accepted it. Here are the details :

My test was with Visual Studio Community 2019, version 16.7.7.

1. I installed Visual Studio from scratch with only the following 3 minimal components
   [image: Minimal components for debugging VBS with Visual Studio Community 2019]

   - Compilers, build tools, and runtimes

     - C++ CMake tools for Windows
     - MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools (v14.27)
   - Debugging and testing

     - Just-In-Time debugger
2. I ran the VBS with the option `/x` to start the debugger 
   `CScript.exe /x Script2.vbs` 
   [image: Cmd CScript.exe /x debug VBS]
3. A popup appears to select the Just-In-Time Debugger, I kept the options as proposed and pressed OK 
   [image: Visual Studio Community 2019 VBS JIT debugger after CScript /x]
4. The VBS code is shown, the debugger stops at the first line of the script 
   [image: Visual Studio Community 2019 VBS JIT debugger]
5. I can add a breakpoint at line 2, watch the variable `a`, and if I press Continue (<kbd>F5</kbd>), that stops at the breakpoint, etc. 
   [image: Visual Studio Community 2019 VBS JIT debugger, watch and breakpoint]

NB: for information, I now see the third debugging option "Script" in VS menu Tools > Options:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I installed Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition on a new installation of Windows 10 and experienced this same problem.

My initial installation of VS included just the ".NET desktop development" workload.

Once I installed the "Python Development" workload, the script option appeared under the Just-In-Time debugging options. No other changes were required.

[image: Visual Studio Installer options]